# Why is this statement setting the value of x when x isn't in it's scope?

Tags: c

I am trying to recreate the arcade game snake.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DELAY 30000

void print_array(int array[10][2]);
void pellet_generator(int y, int x, int pellet_position[9][2], int write_position);

int main(void)
{
  int pellet_position[10][2] = {{0}, {0}};
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  int max_y = 0, max_x = 0;
  int score = 0;
  char ch;

  srand(time(NULL));

  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(FALSE);

  getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);
  pellet_generator(max_y, max_x, pellet_position, 1);

  while((ch = getch()) != 'q')
    {
      getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);
      mvprintw(0, max_x - 10, "Score: %d", score);

      switch (ch)
    {
    case 'w':
      if (y - 1 != -1)
        mvprintw(y, x, " ");
        y--;
      break;
    case 'a':
      if (x - 1 != -1)
        mvprintw(y, x, " ");
        x--;
      break;
    case 's':
      if (y + 1 != max_y)
        mvprintw(y, x, " ");
        y++;
      break;
    case 'd':
      if (x + 1 != max_x - 1)
        {
          mvprintw(y, x, " ");
          x++;
        }
    }

      mvprintw(y, x, "o");

      if (10 == x && y == 10)
    {
      mvprintw(10, 10, "");
      score++;
    }

      refresh();

    }
  sleep(1);

  endwin();
}

void pellet_generator(int y, int x, int pellet_position[9][2], int write_position)
{
  int i, ty, tx;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      if (write_position)
    {
      ty = rand()%y;
      tx = rand()%x;
      pellet_position[i][i] = tx;
      pellet_position[i][i+1] = ty;
      mvprintw(ty, tx, "*");
    }
    }
}
```

It should assign the values from `rand()` to pellet_position with `tx` being in [][0], and `ty` being at [][1] so that I keep track of pellets that have not been picked up yet.

The line
`pellet_position[i][i] = tx;` which is supposed to keep track of the positions
of the pellets is also setting the value of `x` in `main()` to the final value of `tx` on the final iteration of the loop even though it's not in its scope.

Comment: Both indexes in `pellet_position[i][i]` will go out of bounds. That's a bug.

Comment: `int ch;` not char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are causing the problem:

```
  pellet_position[i][i] = tx;
  pellet_position[i][i+1] = ty;
```

Since `pellet_position` is defined as `pellet_position[9][2]`, it only has 9x2 elements. However, you will inevitably access item `[9][10]`. When you go beyond an array's bounds the behavior is undefined, in this case it is stomping on (overwriting) memory in the `main` function.

To fix the problem, declare `pellet_position` with more space (notice I changed the 2 to a 10):

```
int pellet_position[10][10] = {{0}, {0}};
```

And change the function prototype accordingly:

```
void pellet_generator(int y, int x, int pellet_position[10][10], int write_position)
```

Comment: "pellet_position is defined as pellet_position[9][2]" --> as a function parameter, it is more like `pellet_position[ ][2]` .  The 9 has no quantitative meaning here.

Comment: @chux I typically include the value if it is known, this provides a hint to a static analyzer/compiler, allowing it to better detect possible out-of-bounds access. Although I would normally make it a macro so that I don't have to go change all those 10's to 11's when I decide the board needs to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You have `int pellet_position[9][2]` (elsewhere seem to be `[10][2]` - and you read the max anyway, so why use fixed sizes?)

Then in a loop `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` you do `pellet_position[i][i+1] = ty;` so even if the 2nd dimension was 10, you'd be "going off the end" because of `i+1`, but since the second dimension of only 2 you are going waaayyyyy off the end. This is undefined behavior, but in most cases it will mess up the stack and overwrite variables already on the stack - which seems to be what you are seeing.